# flatten xml attribute and text into sibling elements

Tags: xml, xslt, element, flatten

**I am trying to transform an xml file that looks like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records xmlns="http://some.place.net">
    <Record>
         <length unit="in">96</length>
         <width unit="in">3.75</width>
         <height unit="in">1.75</height>
         <weight unit="lbs">8</weight>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

**Into something that looks like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records xmlns="http://some.place.net">
    <Record>
        <length>96</length>
        <lengthunit>in</lengthunit>
        <width>3.75</width>
        <widthunit>in</widthunit>
        <height>1.75</height>
        <heightunit>in</heightunit>
        <weight>8</weight>
        <weightunit>lbs</weightunit>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

**My xlst style sheet looks like this. I can't figure out how to get the new elements to appear as a sibling to the preceding element**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.something.com">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNamespace" select="namespace-uri(/*)"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@unit">
        <xsl:element name="{name(..)}{name()}" namespace="{$vNamespace}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I end up with instead.

```
<Records xmlns="http://some.place.net">
  <Record>
    <length>
      <lengthunit>in</lengthunit>96</length>
    <width>
      <widthunit>in</widthunit>3.75</width>
    <height>
      <heightunit>in</heightunit>1.75</height>
    <weight>
      <weightunit>lbs</weightunit>8</weight>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

Comment: Split `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>` to move the `@*` case out of the `xsl:copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler if you select the element instead of the attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@unit]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$vNamespace}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="{name()}unit" namespace="{$vNamespace}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@unit"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for. so match=*[@unit] will match any element that has an attribute named unit?